# jar cross call in android framework

Tags: android, frameworks, jar

I am modifying jelly bean framework to have only power-off option when long pressing power button.

In `frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java`,

I need to call a class: ShutdownThread to bring out power-off dialog.

`PhoneWindowManager.java` is inside `android.policy.jar`

`ShutdownThread.java` is inside `services.jar`

In services's `Android.mk`, it uses `android.policy library`

```
LOCAL_MODULE:= services

LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android.policy
```

In policy's `Android.mk`, I need to add services library to be able to use ShutdownThread

```
LOCAL_MODULE := android.policy

LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := services (<---I add this)
```

If I only mm the current folder, it compiles fine and works fine.

But when I clean build the android, it gets error that cannot find symbol ShutdownThread.

How to solve situation like this?

Comment: +1 for really different question!

Comment: When you longpress the power button.. by default the power options will be available to shutdown and what not. I'm not exactly you're what you are getting at. Can you provide more feedback and perhaps explain what you are seeing what you expect? Another way is to use the framework SDK to invoke the shutdown instead of doing a Java library dependency.

Comment: Thanks for better text format and reply. When I long press the power button, it brings out global action option. There are 3 option:Power off, Airplane mode, Silent mode. When I continue to press Power off option, it brings out power-off dialog. Now I don't want 3 options, I just want the power-off dialog when long pressing.

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like android.policy.jar is build first and then services.jar. So I can't use classes in service.jar when building android.policy.jar. Anyway or alternative way to solve this?